# SVM - how can I find the kernel of a specific mapping function

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I am studying SVM and I now understand the kernel trick, as we can skip the high dimensional feature space and just use the kernel function. However, if I have a mapping function, how can I find the corresponding kernel?

As an additional question, do practitioners often care about the mapping function, or do they just directly engineer valid kernels?

Comment: If you have to points in your sample, $x_1, x_2$ and your mapping function is $\phi$ then the Kernel $K$ is defined as $K(x_1,x_2)=<\phi(x_1), \phi(x_2)>$  where $<,>$ is the inproduct.

Comment: @fcop Isn't the point of using kernels in SVM to skip the calculation of the mapping function? For example, the mapping function of the gaussian kernel is complicated and infinite dimensional, but we only need to calculate the kernel.

Comment: Yes, but in your question you asked for the Kernel? But the idea is indeed that you don't have to find the transformation, it is implicit in the kernel.

Comment: @fcop How is, then, the kernel easier to compute? We would have to go through the feature mapping regardless. How will that save time?

Comment: In your question you ask: ' if I have the mapping, how can I find the kernel?'. That is what I answered to. Now you seem to have another question, about 'saving time'. The point is not that you save time but that, via the kernel, a mapping to another feature space is used implicitly. So it is the other way around now: what are the conditions for K such that there exists a $\phi$ with the above properties.

Comment: The point with the kernel is that you don't have to find $\phi$ the 'kernel finds it for you'.